# ExcelJS - Add Rows To Existing Worksheet

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, exceljs, jszip

I have some xlsx files stored in an s3 bucket that I am trying to update. To do this, I am creating an array of rows from a series of json files (one at a time). I get the rows from each json file as follows.

```
let worksheetRows = [];

for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

    let data = json;
    worksheetRows.push({ id: data[i]['id'], url: data[i].url.toString(), name: data[i].name })

}
```

I then download the existing xlsx from s3 and pass the stream (existingFileStream) to the function below.

```
async function loadWorkbookAndUpdate(existingFileStream, stream, bucket, worksheetRows, s3ExcelKey) {

    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

    await workbook.xlsx.read(existingFileStream)
        .then(async () => {
            let worksheetUpdated = workbook.getWorksheet('My Sheet');

            for (worksheetRow of worksheetRows) {
                // Add rows in the headers
                worksheetUpdated.addRow([
                    worksheetRow.id,
                    worksheetRow.url,
                    worksheetRow.name,
                ]);
            }
        })

    await workbook.xlsx.write(stream)
        .then(async () => {
            await s3.upload({
                Key: s3ExcelKey,
                Bucket: bucket,
                Body: stream,
                ServerSideEncryption: "AES256",
                ContentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
            }).promise();
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e.message, 'Sorry. The updated master list file (xlsx) for the default images could not be uploaded to s3.')
        });
}
```

I then try to add the worksheetRows to the existing file stream and upload the updated file stream to s3 to be saved as an updated xlsx file. Ninety five percent of the time it works fine, but for a few of the json files I get this error. I verified that the json in the offending files was valid and the excel that the "existingStream" is generated from does not appear to be corrupt.

I am not using jszip, unless ExcelJS has some dependencies on it that I am not aware of...

Invoke Error    {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Corrupted zip or bug: unexpected signature (\x9B\x4C\xF3\x06, expected \x50\x4B\x03\x04)","stack":["Error: Corrupted zip or bug: unexpected signature (\x9B\x4C\xF3\x06, expected \x50\x4B\x03\x04)","    at ZipEntries.checkSignature (/var/task/node_modules/jszip/lib/zipEntries.js:28:19)","    at ZipEntries.readLocalFiles (/var/task/node_modules/jszip/lib/zipEntries.js:121:18)","    at ZipEntries.load (/var/task/node_modules/jszip/lib/zipEntries.js:258:14)","    at /var/task/node_modules/jszip/lib/load.js:48:24","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)","    at async XLSX.load (/var/task/node_modules/exceljs/lib/xlsx/xlsx.js:279:17)","    at async loadWorkbookAndUpdate (/var/task/app.js:176:2)","

Has anyone else run into this issue or have any ideas as to how I can debug this and figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to be some random discrepancies in property names in a few of my json files that were causing my code to try and add an empty array of rows to my worksheet. The error was a little confusing, because I didn't initially realize that ExcelJS had a dependency on jszip and the file I was populating the rows from was valid json. The code above did work once I found the issue in the property names.